# Dropdown in semantic ui can't be made of multiple selection type when wrapped with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, semantic-ui-react

I am using `react semantic ui` `Dropdown`:

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/

and `styled-components`:

https://styled-components.com/

And when I do the following (in `React render` method), it works well:

```
          <Dropdown
            placeholder="Select tags"
            multiple
            fluid
            selection
            options={tagOptions}
            onChange={this.navigateToTag}
          />
```

I can select multiple items in it. But now I am trying to style it the following way:

```
const SelectTagsDropdown = styled(Dropdown)`
  margin: ${props => props.margin || '1em 0em 1em 0em'}
`
```

and then in `render`:

```
          <SelectTagsDropdown
            placeholder="Select tags"
            multiple
            fluid
            selection
            options={tagOptions}
            onChange={this.navigateToTag}
          />
```

And it becomes `not multiple` with only `one selection possible`. How to still make it `multiple`? I tried supplying it in `attrs` like this:

```
styled(Dropdown).attrs({ multiple: true, selection: true, fluid: true })
```

and also directly in the `styled` properties:

```
const SelectTagsDropdown = styled(Dropdown)`
  margin: ${props => props.margin || '1em 0em 1em 0em'};
  multiple: ${props => props.multiple};
`
```

But neither is working.

Comment: Just tried and it works perfectly for me with same code. `"semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2", "styled-components": "^4.4.1"`. Try this versions or maybe `styled(props => <Dropdown {...props} multiple />)`

Comment: Tried, not working either... Hard to say whats going wrong, so weird

Answer (score 1):

I was able to style the `Dropdown` but indirectly by styling the `Grid.Row` that everything was wrapped in:

```
const ControlRow = styled(Grid.Row)`
  .multiple.selection.dropdown {
      margin: 1em 0em 1em 0em !important;
  }
`
```

And then html:

```
    <ControlRow>
        <Grid.Column width={5}>
          <Dropdown
            multiple
            fluid
            selection
            options={myOptions}
            onChange={this.navigateToMyFunc}
          />
     ...
     ...
```