# Color each selected Dropdown item in react semantic-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, styled-components

I have the following `jsx` code (`react-semantic-ui`) in `render` method:

```
{!this.props.loading &&
      <ControlRow>
        <Grid.Column width={5}>
          <Dropdown
            multiple
            fluid
            selection
            options={myOptions}
            onChange={this.navigateToMyFunc}
          />
...
...
```

And I am using `styled-components` to style my elements:

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Unfortunately the only working styling for the `Dropdown` due to some weird specifics of the environment is indirect from `ControlRow`:

```
const ControlsRow = styled(Grid.Row)`
  .ui.multiple.dropdown > .label {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #2185d0;
  }
`
```

See also the following thread: [Dropdown in semantic ui can't be made of multiple selection type when wrapped with styled-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846128/dropdown-in-semantic-ui-cant-be-made-of-multiple-selection-type-when-wrapped-wi)

Now the `Dropdown` as you can see is of type `multiple`. Each selected item should be colored according to the specified in the `myOptions` options. I can pass `myOptions` to the `ControlRow` which will make the array to be accessible in it, but I am not sure how to write the `styled-components` part of it:

```
.ui.multiple.dropdown > .label {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: ${props => props.myOptions..??};
  }
```

I need to also know which item it is to select correct `myOptions` color. Here is how it looks:

[image]

Right now it is just always `blue`, but I need it to be colored according to each option.

> Update

Seems like it is an absent feature in `semantic-ui-react` - coloring by `hex` - codes (only a few regular color names allowed) - so I posted this feature to their `github`:

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use CSS styling for this. And nothing related to Styled Components needs to be done.

[SemanticUI lets you use a custom render function for labels.](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-multiple-custom-label)

You would use it like this:

```
const renderLabel = (option) => ({
  color: option.color,
  content: option.text,
})

const myOptions = [
  { text: "option one", color: "blue" },
  { text: "option two", color: "red" },
  // more options...
]

// ...

<Dropdown
  multiple
  fluid
  selection
  options={myOptions}
  onChange={this.navigateToMyFunc}
  renderLabel={renderLabel} // here
/>
```

This assumes that your option objects have a `color` property and a `text` property. You'll need to adjust to the shape of your option objects.

Also, the `color` property will need to be one of the available [label colors in SemanticUI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/label/#variations-colored):

```
const colors = [
  'red',
  'orange',
  'yellow',
  'olive',
  'green',
  'teal',
  'blue',
  'violet',
  'purple',
  'pink',
  'brown',
  'grey',
  'black',
]
```

Comment: If I add to `renderLabel` `icon: 'user'`, the icon appears, so the values are passed, but color is not working. I tried setting manually to `blue` color and it works but smth like `#b2df8a` does not.

Comment: Read my answer again, I already said what colors are supported...

Comment: Ok, so it is not supported by `semantic-ui` it seems, got it...

Comment: not supported for color like light grey , dark grey etc

Comment: So this answer is a non answer... I mean thanks for explaining renderLabel but the actual answer is NO you have to change the theme for custom colors which is what OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

by default semantic-ui supports selected list of colors. If you need custom label color, you can add your custom css classes and apply the class name to the label.

```
const getOptions = (myOptions : string[]) => {
    return myOptions.map((myValue : string) =>({
        key: myValue,
        text: myValue,
        value: myValue,
        label: { className: setColorClass(myValue), empty: true, circular: true }
    }))
}


function setColorClass(optValue) {
    if (optValue === '1') return 'light-green';
    else if (optValue === '2') return 'sandy-brown';
    else return 'light-coral';

}
```

in your css class you can have the following classes

```
.ui.label.light-green {
    background-color: lightgreen !important;
}
.ui.label.sandy-brown {
    background-color: lightgreen !important;
}
.ui.label.light-coral {
    background-color: lightgreen !important;
}
```

Also if you want to apply label circular color when the value is selected, you can do the following, write a renderLabel function in your react class and apply it in the  compnent

```
function renderLabel(label:any){
    return {
        content: `${label.text}`,
        className: setColorClass(label.text)
    }
}
```

Sample  component

```
<Dropdown
  search
  selection
  closeOnChange
  value={myValue}
  options={getOptions(myOptions)}
  placeholder='Choose from here'
  onChange={handleDropdownChange}
  renderLabel={renderLabel}
/>
```